# post increment operator java

Tags: java, post-increment

I can't make heads or tails of the following code from "java puzzlers" by joshua bloch.

```
public class Test22{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){ 
    j=j++;
  }
  System.out.println(j); //prints 0

  int a=0,b=0;
  a=b++;
  System.out.println(a);
  System.out.println(b); //prints 1


 }
}
```

I can't get the part where j prints 0.
According to the author,

```
j=j++
```

is similar to

```
temp=j;
j=j+1;
j=temp;
```

But

```
a=b++
```

makes b 1.
So it should've evaluated like this,

```
a=b
b=b+1
```

By following the same logic, shouldn't

```
j=j++
```

be evaluated as,

```
j=j
j=j+1
```

Where does the temp come into picture here?
Any explanations would be much appreciated. << I'm breaking my head over this. ;)>>
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29):

Let's break down your own argument:

> According to the author,
>
> ```
> j=j++;
> ```
>
> is similar to
>
> ```
> temp=j;
> j=j+1;    // increment
> j=temp;   // then assign
> ```

Yes, you're right so far..., but here's where you got it wrong:

> But
>
> ```
> a=b++;
> ```
>
> makes `b=1`. So it should've evaluated like this,
>
> ```
> a=b;      // assign
> b=b+1;    // then increment
> ```

WRONG! You're not applying the rule consistently! You've changed the order from *increment then assign* to *assign then increment*!!! It's actually evaluated like this:

```
temp=b;
b=b+1;     // increment
a=temp;    // then assign
```

Basically assignments of this form:

```
lhs = rhs++;
```

is similar to doing something like this:

```
temp = rhs;
rhs = rhs+1;  // increment
lhs = temp;   // then assign
```

Apply this to `a = b++;`. Then apply it also to `j = j++;`. That's why you get the results that you get.

What you did was *you came up with your own interpretation* of what `a = b++;` does -- a WRONG interpretation that doesn't follow the above rule. That's the source of your confusion.

---

#### See also

- [JLS 15.14.2 Postfix Increment Operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.14.2)

  > "...the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable [...] The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored."

Answer (score 12):

The post increment operator implicitly uses a temp variable.  This allows it to return one value while setting its argument to another.  That's why

```
a = b++;
```

Can increment `b`, but set `a` to the *old value* of `b`.  The same thing is going on with

```
j = j++;
```

The variable is incremented on the right hand side, but it's then set back to the old value when the assignment takes place.

Comment: I had a different perspective from this explanation. Thanks for your time mate.

Comment: Good explanation. Unfortunately, in C/C++ that behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

`j++` will use the old value of `j` and then it will increment it. But when it overwrites the left hand side, it will use the old value of j.

It is similar to :

```
temp=j;
j += 1; 
j=temp;     // take the old value of j.
```