# Different result same expression in C, C++ and Java. WHY?

Tags: java, c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
int i = 10;
int n = i++*5*i;
```

Output

value of n = 550 (in Java)
value of n = 500 (in C and C++ )

Why not same result? Why different?

Comment: Could it be because they're different languages?

Comment: Anyone who attempts to use code like that in any language should be taken out back and shot.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: not much different to some lambdas I've seen....

Comment: I think people are surprised when a mature, common language such as C or C++ react in an unpredictable way. It's so contrary to the usual programming experience. That's why this question keeps coming up.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, this is a well defined operation. It will:

1. increment `i` (it's now 11);
2. Produce the old value of `i` (10), because you used the [*postfix increment* operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750216/post-increment-operator-java/2750233#2750233);
3. Multiply that by 5 (10*5 = 50);
4. Multiply that by the current value of `i` (50*11 = 550);

In both C and C++ [this operation has undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4176333#4176333), so anything could happen. If anything could happen, that explains the results, whatever they are, and whether they make sense to you or not.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, operations such as:

```
j = i++ + i;
```

are undefined, due to lack of sequence points.  In Java, they are well defined.  Therefore, you could see a difference in results.

Comment: Forgive me for nitpicking, but that's not a correct use of "therefore" - he could easily have seen the same results, they just happened to be evaluated in a different order. In other words, '550' could well be output by the C++ code.

Comment: I thought that the operators were handled with same priorities in C C++ and Java but it seems that Java handles differently. 

In the context of JAVA

++ has more high priority than % as documentation http://w3i.in/754

int i = 10;
int n = i++*5*i;

in this case i++ is done but if expression is as follows:

int i = 10;
int n = i++*5;

then i++ is handled after multiplication even though multiplication has lower priority.

why?

Comment: @Arafangion: "Therefore" seems fine to me.  The first sentence is a statement; the second statement is the conclusion.  (Note that I was careful to say "could", not "will".)

Comment: @Anand: It's nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: @Anand it's not possible to reason about this in terms of operator precedence. You must understand what a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) is.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are doing is undefined. The increment operator should not be placed in expressions of assignment with the variable being incremented.

```
i = i++; //undefined
n = i++ + i; // also undefined
```

Comment: He's not using it as such. He's doing (i++) * 5 * i. The question is when does i get incremented.

Comment: What does being dyadic have to do with this?

Comment: Yes, this answer is nonsense (apart from the part that says that this is undefined).

Comment: Still nonsense.  What's wrong with `int n; n = i++;`?

Comment: This is **still** not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Benjamin nothing; but that's because `n` is not "the variable being incremented", so it isn't a case that the answerer is describing.

Comment: @Karl: My comment was in response to the second version of this answer, you're looking at the third.

Comment: @Karl: but it is a lot more like the case that the *questioner* was describing. The question does no have `i` on both sides of the assignment.