# counting letters and spaces

Tags: java

I need to count letters and spaces in some string. output is the string of mine

I tried this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
        if (output.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            letters = letters++;
        } //counting spaces
        else {
            spaces = spaces++;
        }
```

It doesn't work. I get 0 letters and 0 spaces. I suppose I need some code instead ' ', right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
letters = letters++;
```

is wrong. (Same for `spaces`.) See [here](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/PostIncrementOperatorAndAssignment) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750216/post-increment-operator-java) for an explanation: `letters` is unchanged after that line.

Either use:

```
letters = letters + 1;
```

or simply:

```
letters++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Character.isSpaceChar` and `Character.isLetter` method. ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html))

Comment: it's a better solution for sure... however answer is rather below. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The java `Character` class has helper methods that you could use:

```
int letters = 0, spaces = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++)
{
    char c = output.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(c))
    {
        letters++;
    }
    else if (Character.isWhitespace(c))
    {
        spaces++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = letters++;
```

should be

```
letters++;
```

because `letters = letters++;`

is equivalent to,

```
int temp = letters;
letters++;
letters = temp;
```

which does not increment the value of `letters`

[This classic Q/A of SO has more insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop)