# Difference between prefix and postfix operators in different situations

Tags: java

I have gone through all the questions in this forum that are corresponding to this topic, and I felt to raise a different question as this question is not answered clearly. Here is my scenario:
I have this class Test1:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int i=0, j=2;
        do {
            i= i+1;
            j--;
        } while(j>0);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Now this is my question:
a) If I replace the increment operation of 'i= i+1' with ++i, I get the desired output as

```
1
2
```

But if I replace the increment operation of 'i= i+1' with i++, I get the desired output as

```
0
0
```

I do understand the difference of using prefix and postfix operators in for loop, but why is the value not getting incremented at all in do-while loop?

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't increment as expected (i.e. the i++ one).

Comment: You only have one print statement. How are you seeing two lines?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the do-while loop and is probably because you've changed `i = i + 1;` to `i = i++;`. If you don't know what's wrong with that you should go back and read all those questions again.

Comment: You replaced `i = i + 1` with `i++`, literally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post increment operator java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750216/post-increment-operator-java). @whoAmI - try to avoid closing as a duplicate of a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Using `i = i++;` will never change `i` value.

Use just:

```
i++;
```

Why? because:

```
i = i++;
```

is similar to doing something like this:

```
temp = i;  // temp is 0.
i = i+1;  // increment i
i = temp;   // assign temp (which is 0) to i.
```

Take a look at a [similar post-increament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750216/post-increment-operator-java/2750233#2750233) question and [even another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453948/a-field-to-count-the-amount-instances-of-a-class/20453962#20453962).

Answer (score 2):

```
++i
```

This will increment `i`, *then* return it.

```
i++
```

This will return `i`, *then* increment it.

**Example**

[Here](http://ideone.com/Usezzm) is a link to an ideone example of this.

```
int i = 5;
System.out.println(i++);

// Outputs 5

int j = 5;
System.out.println(++j);

// Outputs 6.
```

Comment: But that's not what he's asking

Comment: Maybe emphasize that `i=i+1` has similar behavior to `++i`, as opposed to `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

`x = i++;` is a shortcut for `x = i; i = i + 1;`

`x = ++i;` is a shortcut for `i = i + 1; x = i;`

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your sample, there should be no difference between `i++` and `++i`, if you replace `i = i+1` by one of two. Chris noted the difference correctly, I'll just add a sample, where this is important:

```
int i = 0;
method(i++);
```

Will call `method` with the original value of `0` and increment `i` afterwords. In `method`, however, you'll see the original value `0`.

```
int i = 0;
method(++i);
```

Will increment `i` and then call `method`. So in `method` you'll get the value of `1`. That does not change the fact that after `method`, `i` has the value `1` in both cases.

---

Others have noted correctly that

```
i = ++i;
```

and

```
i = i++;
```

*are* different things actually!