# Why can't I get indexOf() to equal anything other than 0 in this code?

Tags: java, iteration, indexof, anagram

My main goal is to get a value of `-1` for `indexOf` every time a letter is not found in the word it is being searched for in. I can use this value to determine if the words are `anagrams` or not. The issue, however, is that I am continually getting `0` for `indexOf`. Shouldn't I be getting `-1` if the letters are completely different?.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class anagram
{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first word");
        String a = kbReader.next();
        System.out.println("Enter second word");
        String b = kbReader.next(); ///User inputs 2 strings, a and b
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();

        int numA = a.length();
        int numB = b.length();

        if (numA != numB)
           System.out.println("NOT AN ANAGRAM"); 



        for(int i = 0;i < numA; i++) ///continues until all letters are used
        {
            String letter = b.substring(i,i++);
            int checker = a.indexOf(letter);///checks word a for every letter of b

            System.out.println(checker); ///always get 0 for this value, why never -1?



       }
   }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about "always zero" but `indexOf()` returns the index of the first letter.  I'm not sure what is you are trying to achieve with it.  (You're also incrementing i++ too many times.)

Comment: OK, you're using the `String` version of `indexOf`.  `substring(i,i++)` always returns an empty string, and the empty string always matches an empty string at the very beginning of any string.  So the empty string `letter` is the problem, and the root of that is your index values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to why you cannot get any thing other that 0 from indexOf():

In this statement, `String letter = b.substring(i,i++);`
lets say you are in second iteration (that is i = 2) in the `for` loop.
You have used a post increment operator, that means first the statement is executed and then the value is incremented.

In that case `b.substring(i,i++);` resolves to `b.substring(2,2);`
and you get `String letter = ""`

According to implementation of indexOf(), index of "" in any string is returned as 0 and this is where purpose of your logic gets defeated.

Just for understanding purpose I will paste the implemantation of indexOf() from String.java class:

> ```
> /**
>  * Code shared by String and StringBuffer to do searches. The
>  * source is the character array being searched, and the target
>  * is the string being searched for.
>  *
>  * @param   source       the characters being searched.
>  * @param   sourceOffset offset of the source string.
>  * @param   sourceCount  count of the source string.
>  * @param   target       the characters being searched for.
>  * @param   targetOffset offset of the target string.
>  * @param   targetCount  count of the target string.
>  * @param   fromIndex    the index to begin searching from.
>  */
> static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
>         char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
>         int fromIndex) {
>     if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
>         return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
>     }
>     if (fromIndex < 0) {
>         fromIndex = 0;
>     }
>     if (targetCount == 0) {
>         return fromIndex;
>     }
>
>     char first = target[targetOffset];
>     int max = sourceOffset + (sourceCount - targetCount);
>
>     for (int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
>         /* Look for first character. */
>         if (source[i] != first) {
>             while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);
>         }
>
>         /* Found first character, now look at the rest of v2 */
>         if (i <= max) {
>             int j = i + 1;
>             int end = j + targetCount - 1;
>             for (int k = targetOffset + 1; j < end && source[j]
>                     == target[k]; j++, k++);
>
>             if (j == end) {
>                 /* Found whole string. */
>                 return i - sourceOffset;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return -1;
> }
> ```

Here targetCount is 0 and you get 0 value returned in your code.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
String letter = b.substring(i,i + 1);
```

See also [post increment operator java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750216/post-increment-operator-java)

By the way, Strings of equal size does not mean that they are Anagrams

Comment: *Strings of equal size does not mean that they are Anagrams* - yes, but unequal size strings do mean that they are definitely not anagrams, which is what OP has done

Comment: @Kartik - well maybe that is what he is heading towards eh.

Comment: but he did not break when strings are unequal, and that code is not perfect, just want to give heads up to OP

Comment: Kartlik is right, Deadpool is right - now just upvote me.

Comment: lol yeah, would like to see the completed code.. just put an `else` right before the for-loop to solve the breaking problem :D

Comment: @Kartik I am now getting the correct value for indexOf, and also added an else statement. One issue left, however, how do I break out of the for loop to state whether it is an anagram or not? Edit: I cant post the code in a comment, first time using stack, ima figure this out one sec...